# How to get Media URL with custom width and media protection hash using Scriban

Tags: sxa, scriban

I need separate image fields for mobile and desktop and trying to render it using Scriban in picture tag as below.

*Current Scriban code:*

```
<picture>
     <source srcset="{{ i_item.MyMobileImage.media_url }}" media="(max-width: 767px)">
     <source srcset="{{ i_item.MyDesktopImage.media_url }}" media="(min-width: 768px)">
</picture>
```

Is there a OOTB way to get image url with specific width and media protection hash using Scriban? or Writing Scriban extension is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is an ootb way to do this (yet). A small [extension](https://ggullentops.blogspot.com/2019/11/custom-sxa-scriban-extensions.html) could help you here. Something like this (not tested):

```
public class MediaUrl : IGenerateScribanContextProcessor
{
    private readonly IContext context;

    public MediaUrl(IContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void Process(GenerateScribanContextPipelineArgs args)
    {
        var url = new GetMediaUrl(GetUrl);
        args.GlobalScriptObject.Import("sc_fullmediaurl", (Delegate)url);
    }

    public string GetUrl(Item item, string field, string width)
    {
        var options = new MediaUrlOptions { ... };
        var url = MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(mediaItem, options);
        return HashingUtils.ProtectAssetUrl(url);
    }

    private delegate string GetMediaUrl(Item item, string field, string width);
}
```

Another option could be to use **[sc_execute](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/93/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/the-embedded-functions-for-the-scriban-template.html#idp23148)** and a **responsive image** variant. This way you use the ootb functionality of SXA to get responsive images instead of having 2 image fields.